# How to calculate heuristic shooting star algorithm?

Tags: pgrouting, routing, shooting-star

I have a problem with the shooting star algorithm.  It's my final project and I need some help.

My question is how can I calculate the heuristic shooting star algorithm?
I can use the **[pgrouting shooting star](http://pgrouting.org/docs/foss4g2008/ch09.html)**, but I don't understand how to calculate heuristic shooting star.

I have searched the calculating heuristic shooting star in internet book but I can't find it now.

---

Can you tell me  about  shooting star algorithm, not just source code , Mr Mario?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, and I am not an expert, but maybe you can find something in the [source code](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/core/src/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.cpp#L100) of pgrouting shooting star heuristic function and modify it too your needs. Of course, your would have to build pgrouting again.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Mario Miler,your source code is same with pgrouting or library in Postgresql, Postgis.Right?

Comment: This is source code from pgrouting repository. You will have download the whole repository, change heuristic function of your choice and build it. You can find some instructions here http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install_ubuntu.html .. little, old but should work. I haven't build pgrouting for some time now so cant tell you if there are any problems.

Comment: Can you tell me  about shooting star algorithm, Mr Mario?

Comment: Can you tell me about shooting star algorithm, not just source code , Mr Mario?

Comment: Shooting start is just a fancy name for what is essentially still A*. It just routes between links instead of nodes. See this discussion: http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/discussion/topic/276.html

Comment: Looking at the source code, it also seems like both heuristics assume projected coordinates, which means they are not correct for typical lat/long data.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I get this one from mailing list. Shooting* is edge-based, so it goes from edge to edge while A* and Dijkstra go vrom vertex to vertex. Thus you need a data structure which keeps all adjacent edges for every edge of your graph. It can be also done by making a line graph (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) out your original road network

Comment: And then you can assign an edge-to-edge passage cost (as a special attribute of your adjacent edges structure or as a cost of the line graph) which actually represents any kind of limitations or penalties for going from one edge to another - such as turn restrictions in a case of turns or any other kind of restrictions like traffic lights. Having this you can use A* or any other shortest path algorithm using edges as vertices.

So, that's an idea behind the Shooting*.

Comment: And I get this one agaian from Anton Patrushev: http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/discussion/topic/276.html. You write like this: In A* we are using something similar to Manhattan function (|Dx|+|Dy|)/2 http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/browser/trunk/core/src/astar_boost_wrapper.cpp#L75 There you'll see other attempts commented out. We tried different function is OK.

Comment: Probably, it was historical reason. heuristic function and for some reason (I don't remember now) decided that for a common road network this In Shooting* we are using Euclidian distance. http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/browser/trunk/core/src/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.cpp#L100 .

The other formula: - Euclidean distance > Sqrt(Dx²+Dy²+Dz²) ; - Manhattan distance > |Dx|+|Dy|+|Dz| ; - Maximum distance > Max(|Dx|, |Dy|, |Dz|).

I still don’t understand about all.Friend, Can you tell me briefly and detail of The process algorithm shooting star?

Answer (score 1):

I get this one from mailing list.
Shooting* is edge-based, so it goes from edge to edge while A* and
Dijkstra go vrom vertex to vertex. Thus you need a data structure
which keeps all adjacent edges for every edge of your graph. It can be
also done by making a line graph
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) out your original road
network. And then you can assign an edge-to-edge passage cost (as a
special attribute of your adjacent edges structure or as a cost of the
line graph) which actually represents any kind of limitations or
penalties for going from one edge to another - such as turn
restrictions in a case of turns or any other kind of restrictions like
traffic lights. Having this you can use A* or any other shortest path
algorithm using edges as vertices.

So, that's an idea behind the Shooting*.

And I get this one agaian from Anton Patrushev:
http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/discussion/topic/276.html. You write like this: In A* we are using something similar to Manhattan function (|Dx|+|Dy|)/2 http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/browser/trunk/core/src/astar_boost_wrapper.cpp#L75 
There you'll see other attempts commented out. 
We tried different function is OK. Probably, it was historical reason. heuristic function and for some reason (I don't remember now) decided that for a common road network this 
In Shooting* we are using Euclidian distance. http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/browser/trunk/core/src/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.cpp#L100 .

The other formula:
- Euclidean distance > Sqrt(Dx²+Dy²+Dz²) ;
- Manhattan distance > |Dx|+|Dy|+|Dz| ;
- Maximum distance > Max(|Dx|, |Dy|, |Dz|).

I still don’t understand about all.Friend, Can you tell me briefly and detail of The process algorithm shooting star?